# How to check if all values exists inside nested object elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have following document in ES :

```
[
  {
    "event_id": 123,
    "event_name": "test event",
    "event_date": "2018-12-21",
    "ticket_group": [
      {
        "available": 8,
        "price": 8,
        "id": "159831",
        "parking_passes_available": 0,
        "field_values": [
          {
            "field_id": 589,
            "field_value": "KUMAR"
          },
          {
            "field_id": 717,
            "field_value": "AMIT"
          },
          {
            "field_id": 1360,
            "field_value": "SAM"
          },
          {
            "field_id": 2239,
            "field_value": ""
          },
          {
            "field_id": 2240,
            "field_value": ""
          },
          {
            "field_id": 2241,
            "field_value": ""
          },
          {
            "field_id": 2242,
            "field_value": ""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and i want to search with multiple field_id and field_value with AND operator. But it works if there is single condition but not for multiple cases. Here is what i have tried so far :

```
    {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "ticket_group",
            "score_mode": "max",
            "inner_hits": {
              "from": 0,
              "size": 10000
            },
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "ticket_group.field_values",
                      "score_mode": "max",
                      "inner_hits": {
                        "from": 0,
                        "size": 10000
                      },
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                  {
                                    "match": {
                                      "ticket_group.field_values.field_id": 589
                                    }
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "match": {
                                      "ticket_group.field_values.field_value": "KUMAR"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                  {
                                    "match": {
                                      "ticket_group.field_values.field_id": 717
                                    }
                                  },
                                 {
                                    "match": {
                                      "ticket_group.field_values.field_value": "AMIT"
                                    }
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": {
    "event_date": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

i want to search ticket group if field_id=717 with value "amit" and field_id=589 with value "kumar" exists in field_values object inside ticket_group. Using above query i am getting no records while objects with both values exist in field_values.
Can anyone help to build a such query ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is what you are looking for. You simply need to push the second level nested into two `must` clauses.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "nested":{  
                  "path":"ticket_group",
                  "score_mode":"max",
                  "inner_hits":{  

                  },
                  "query":{  
                     "bool":{  
                        "must":[  
                           {  
                              "nested":{  
                                 "path":"ticket_group.field_values",
                                 "score_mode":"max",
                                 "inner_hits":{  
                                    "name":"inner_clause_1"
                                 },
                                 "query":{  
                                    "bool":{  
                                       "must":[  
                                          {  
                                             "match":{  
                                                "ticket_group.field_values.field_id":589
                                             }
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "match":{  
                                                "ticket_group.field_values.field_value":"KUMAR"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           {  
                              "nested":{  
                                 "path":"ticket_group.field_values",
                                 "score_mode":"max",
                                 "inner_hits":{  
                                    "name":"inner_clause_2"
                                 },
                                 "query":{  
                                    "bool":{  
                                       "must":[  
                                          {  
                                             "match":{  
                                                "ticket_group.field_values.field_id":717
                                             }
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "match":{  
                                                "ticket_group.field_values.field_value":"AMIT"
                                             }
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Notice that I've named the `inner_hits` in the *second level nested* queries.

If you don't do that(try by removing the `name` key in the `inner_hits`), then you would only see the `inner_hit` for the *last clause* which ends up overwriting the `inner_hits` result of the *first nested clause*.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Kamal , Searching working as expected but getting inner_clause_1 and inner_clause_2 as empty array

Comment: @AmitPanwar Which ES version are you using? I've tested it both on ES 6.4 and ES 5.5 and it works as expected. Also could you remove the name parameter and see what do you observe? Like `"inner_hits": {}`

Comment: it's 2.3.2, Its pretty old.  by removing name i am not getting inner hits for these clauses we added.

Comment: @AmitPanwar I'm afraid, it looks like there was on issue/bug as per this link https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13064 and it is only available post `5.x` version onwards. There is a much verbose way which you can try to construct as per this link https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13064#issuecomment-135524830 but I'm not sure(also I am unable to start ES 2.3.2 on my mac, giving me some errors). You can give it a try and let me know if that works.